# Alternative to zk:template tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, zk

I'm using zk:template tag on my jsp page which displays the table with some data (I'm using MVVM approach)

The page looks in general the following way:

```
<z:window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('my.package.MyDataViewModel')">
     <z:grid id="myDataGrid" model="@load(vm.myData.list)">
       <z:columns>
           <z:column>Column1</z:column>
           <z:column>Column2</z:column>
           <z:column>Column3</z:column>
           <z:column>Column4</z:column>
       </z:columns>
       <z:rows>
       <zk:template name="model">
                <z:row>
                    <z:label value="@load(each.property1)" />
                    <z:label value="@load(each.property2)" />
                    <z:label value="@load(each.property3)" />
                    <z:label value="@load(each.property4)" />
                </z:row>
            </zk:template>
        </z:rows>
     </z:grid>
</z:window>
```

The problem is that because of zk:template tag I'm getting the following exception: "UnsupportedOperationException - please use jsp template instead"

I tried to google it and it seems that its normal behavior of this tag but I don't understand what should I use instead of it. I tried to use JSTL's c:forEach tag but I couldn't achieve the result that z:template tag can provide.

**Updated:** 
I'm using ZK version 6.5.2 and JSP Tags version 2.0

Comment: Can you tell me which version  zk  and jsp tag  you use, i thing its version  exception  http://zkjsp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r92/trunk/zkjsp/zkdoc/zkjsp-release-note

Comment: Why is your template tag like this -> "<zk:template>"?

Answer (score 0):

i think  its version compatible problem .

May be this link give you solution:

http://zkjsp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r92/trunk/zkjsp/zkdoc/zkjsp-release-note